libcurl compile fail, OpenSSL could not be detected
I compiled openssl using static mode using command
export CC="gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-unwind-tables -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-math-errno -fPIC"; ./config no-err shared --libdir=lib --prefix=/home/user/openssl/windows-x64-shared --openssldir=/home/user/openssl/windows-x64-shared  -DOPENSSL_SMALL_FOOTPRINT && make -j8 && make -j8 install_sw

And then i tried to compile libcurl, with usage of my own OpenSSL library using command
LDFLAGS="-static" PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config --static" ./configure --prefix=/home/user/curl-org/windows-x64-static --with-openssl=/home/user/openssl/windows-x64-shared --disable-shared --enable-static && make -j8 curl_LDFLAGS=-all-static && make install

I used GCC from here:
https://winlibs.com/#download-release
GCC 14.2.0 (with POSIX threads) + LLVM/Clang/LLD/LLDB 18.1.8 + MinGW-w64 12.0.0 (MSVCRT)
OpenSSL version: 3.3.1
CURL version: 8.8.0
During curl configure, it throws an error
configure: PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR will be set to "/home/user/openssl/windows-x64-shared/lib/pkgconfig"
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for openssl options with pkg-config... found
configure: pkg-config: SSL_LIBS: "-lssl -lcrypto"
configure: pkg-config: SSL_LDFLAGS: ""
configure: pkg-config: SSL_CPPFLAGS: ""
checking for HMAC_Update in -lcrypto... no
checking for HMAC_Init_ex in -lcrypto... no
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl... no
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl and -lpthread... no
checking for SSL_set_quic_use_legacy_codepoint... no
configure: OpenSSL version does not speak QUIC API
configure: OPT_OPENSSL: /home/user/openssl/windows-x64-shared
configure: OPENSSL_ENABLED:
configure: error: --with-openssl was given but OpenSSL could not be detected

What i did wrong? I want to use GCC MSVCRT due to portability reasons
